# Change WSO2AM API token timeouts

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm working on the project that consume data from WSO2AM. I'm following steps from https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/publisher/#guide and everything is OK.

I want to change the token expired duration for the logged in user (not application subscription token). The only think I know to achieve this is by [changing the configuration on the WSO2 application](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Token+API#TokenAPI-Configuringthetokenexpirationtime) itself.

Is there any other way to dat from the consumer end? maybe by putting the expiration duration as query string?

This is the curl command to get the token:

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin&scope=apim:api_view" -H "Authorization: Basic SGZFbDFqSlBkZzV0YnRyeGhBd3liTjA1UUdvYTpsNmMwYW9MY1dSM2Z3ZXpIaGM3WG9HT2h0NUFh" https://localhost:8243/token
```

This is the response:

```
{
    "scope":"apim:api_view",
    "token_type":"Bearer",
    "expires_in":3600,
    "refresh_token":"33c3be152ebf0030b3fb76f2c1f80bf8",
    "access_token":"292ff0fd256814536baca0926f483c8d"
}
```

Basically I want the value of `expires_in` from the response to be last longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the OAuth2 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.2), users aren't allowed to request for token expiry time. Therefore, it's a server-side configuration.

However, WSO2 provides this capability for client credentials grant type for the ease of developers to test their apps with different token expiry times.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply increase the expiration time of your OAuth token and Refresh tokens generally by changing the following configuration in "***conf/identity/identity.xml***"

```
        <!-- Default validity period for Authorization Code in seconds -->
        <AuthorizationCodeDefaultValidityPeriod>300</AuthorizationCodeDefaultValidityPeriod>
        <!-- Default validity period for application access tokens in seconds -->
        <AccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod>3600</AccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod>
        <!-- Default validity period for user access tokens in seconds -->
        <UserAccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod>3600</UserAccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod>
        <!-- Validity period for refresh token -->
        <RefreshTokenValidityPeriod>84600</RefreshTokenValidityPeriod>
        <!-- Timestamp skew in seconds -->
        <TimestampSkew>300</TimestampSkew>
```

You have the ability to change the validity time/expiration time for each application also by changing the validity period for the generated OAuth token per each application with relevant value in API Manager.

Comment: Per application one is valid only for client credential grant type.

Comment: @Bee: if we are using grant type as password. Does it allow to change the validity time in APIM 2.5.0

Comment: You mean to send the expiry time in the request? Then, no.

Comment: @Bee: not in request, by default when ever I am generating token.. it should have validity of 5 days(432000 seconds) instead of 3600 seconds

Comment: For that you can use above configs: `AccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod ` (for client-credentials grant)` and `UserAccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod` (for other grants)